# Get the nameof supplied generic type in a generic interface

Tags: c#

Suppose having the following interface:

```
public interface ITraceManager<TManager> where TManager : class
    {
        string Name { get; }
        void DisplayName();
    }
```

A concrete class implementing this interface looks like the following:

```
public sealed class TraceManager<TManager> : ITraceManager<TManager> where TManager : class
    {
        public string Name => $"Foo Bar - {nameof(TManager)}";        

        public void DisplayName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name}");            
        }
    }
```

I can register this dependency by constructor like the following:

```
readonly ITraceManager<LoginManager> _traceManager;
public LoginManager(ITraceManager<LoginManager> traceManager)
{
   _traceManager = traceManager;
}
```

when invoking the `_traceManager.DisplayName()` method, I'd expect the `Name` property to retain the value of `nameof(LoginManager)` since that is the supplied type. However, instead, the value of `Name` property is `TManager`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want `typeof(TManager).Name`. `nameof` returns the name of the _generic argument_ i.e. `TManager`, not the name of the supplied type.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thank you! That did it. Please feel free to add your comment in as an answer, and I'll mark it as an accepted answer.